# How can I print an array in reverse?

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

This is my array code and I need to print it in reverse.

```
public class Array1D {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[3];
        array[0] = 1;
        array[1] = 2;
        array[2] = 5;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { //loop
            System.out.print("array["+i+"]=");
            System.out.println(array[i] + "   ");
        }
        System.out.println("the last element in the matrix = " + array[array.length - 1]); // finding the last element in the array
        System.out.println("   ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Well... `for(int i=array.length-1; i>=0; i--)` should help ;)

Comment: @nasyia - If you have a solution to your problem don't forget to accept the answer that helped you most by clicking the grey tick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just reverse the direction of your for loop. Right now it is counting from 0 to the length, have it count from the length to zero

```
for (int i = array.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to reverse the array, use:

```
ArrayUtils.reverse(int[] array)
```

But I suggest using a reversed loop.

Answer (score -4):

try like this (sample pseudocode) :

```
for (i=array length-1;i=>0;i--){
print(i);
}
```

Comment: The first iteration will be out of bounds, the zero index element will not be printed, and the counter is going up.

Comment: Nizil : This is just to give him an idea of what to do (I mentioned sample pseudocode), I know he will get an array index out of bounds , but he will know how array works if he can fix that

Comment: @RajarshiGoswami But your counter is increasing, which is the complete and total opposite of what OP wants to do. This gives almost no idea of what to do.

Comment: Michelle Sorry My bad.. Fixed that now

Comment: @RajarshiGoswami Well, you're right, the index out of bounds not matter. I was speaking for the counter ;)